# Rails Formtastic does not show error message for date field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, formtastic

I have  a Formtastic form like:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @event do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :starts_at %><br />
    <%= form.datetime_select :starts_at, :discard_year => true, :minute_step => 30 %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my Event.rb, I have:

```
  validates_inclusion_of :starts_at, :in => Time.now..(Time.now + 1.year), 
                     :message => "appointment must be between now and one year from now"
```

It seems that the validation works (prevent instances with invalid date from being saved), but the error message does not show in the form. I have other fields with validations and they all show message that I specified in Event.rb

I wonder what I did wrong, or there's something special about date field.

Answer (score 1):

To see the error message you need to access the the errors method. I call a helper method inside the form:

`render_form_errors(form)`

Where the helper method is:

```
def render_form_errors(form)
  object = form.object

  if object && object.errors.any?
    message = 'Please fix these errors, then try again:'.html_safe
    content_tag :div, message + form.semantic_errors(*object.errors.keys), :class => "form-error ui-state-error ui-corner-all"
  else
    ''
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. I am curious why other errors are handled correctly by Formtastic though.

Comment: It just occurred to me that if you are using formtastic 2, it uses HTML5 attributes to stop the form being saved. In some cases (for me it was WYSIWYG fields using CK Editor) the HTML5 messages were hidden because of the way the EDitor inserts itself into the page.